# Point to memory block held by a char array or copy that char array to the passed char params in the function?

Tags: arrays, c, char

I have the following method

```
void foo(FILE*, char*, char*);
```

I am calling this method from main. I then compare a value and want the name and surname with the least of that value in the method.

I read the file from the FILE* and want to modify/work it in such a way that I can end up doing the following in main.

```
char* name;
char* sname;
foo(file, name, sname);
printf("\nSurname: %s\nName: %s\n\n", *sname, *name);
```

I have tried `memcopy` and `strncpy` but I end up on segmentation fault.

The `foo` looks like:

```
while(fscanf() != EOF)
{
  if(certain value is smaller than held value)
  {
    //update smallest value;
    //point to that name and surname to whom smallest value belongs to;
  }
}
```

Sorry if I am asking something really simple or direct. I am from C++ background `std::string` and now struggling with this. Any help, or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have uninitialized pointers you are trying to dereference.  That won't work -- you need to make them point at something first.

Comment: `char *` is just a pointer. It does not point/refer to any valid memory until you explicitly set it with such a valid memory address. There are several ways to fix that but one simple one is to change those to char arrays: `char name[MAX_LEN];`. Be aware that buffer overflows need to be handled if using fixed array sizes like this.

Comment: And for the `printf` the `%s` specifier requires a string. `*sname` is a `char`. So remove the `*`.

Comment: C is 100% pass by value. You pass the values of `name` and `sname` to `foo` -- but you never assign them any values. It's no different from `void foo(int); ... int j; foo(j);` -- you'd be passing no particular value to `foo`.

Comment: The size parameter of `strncpy` is normally used to make sure you don't copy more characters than would fit in the destination array. In order to do this you would have to pass the array size to `foo` in addition to the address. Note that `strncpy` doesn't append a terminating `'\0'` if the source string is too long for the specified size.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I managed to fix it by changing `char*` to `char []` and removing the dereferencing from the `printf()`.

Comment: @Bodo Thank you very much. I have fixed the warning as well by replacing it with the defined length.

Comment: Are you sure you've allocated memory for these string buffers? `char* x` does not actually allocate. `char x[]` doesn't either.

Comment: @tadman Yes. I did `char var[W_LENGTH] = { '\0'}`

Comment: There's a big difference between a sized array like that and `char[]` which is what I thought you meant.

Comment: @tadman I meant to insinuate `char array`. I am sorry if that caused any confusion.

Comment: If you got this working it's worth adding a self-answer to not only close it out, but to cement whatever you've learned here. Helps to retain that knowledge.